# How do I put this into a While?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
skill=input("What is your skill leavel ? E or C ? (Expert of casual): ")
if skill == "E":
    print ("Expert")
elif skill == "C":
    print ("Casual")
```

How do I implement a `while` loop so when a user inputs an answer other than E or C it will ask again?

Comment: This sounds like a very simple while loop. What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

There are no `do-until` loops in Python. Common way is to `while True`:

```
while True:
    skill=input("What is your skill leavel ? E or C ? (Expert of casual): ")
    if skill == "E":
        print ("Expert")
        break
    elif skill == "C":
        print ("Casual")
        break
    print("Invalid input, try again:")
```

Alternative:

```
valid_input = {'E' : 'Expert', 'C': 'Causal'}
skill = None

while skill not in valid_input:
    skill=input("What is your skill leavel ? E or C ? (Expert or casual): ")

print(valid_input[skill])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like this (note i am not good with python syntax):

so create a function named a loop, and then add a statement that says that if(skill=!c and skill=!e) then it calls itself

Answer (score 0):

```
  while True:
    skill=input("What is your skill leavel ? E or C ? (Expert of casual): ")
    if skill == "E":
        print ("Expert")
    elif skill == "C":
        print ("Casual")
    elif skill == "Q":
        break;
```

Use an infinite loop while true, then break when you want to exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you might need:

```js
while (True):
    kill=input("What is your skill leavel ? E or C ? (Expert of casual): ")
    if kill == "E":
        print ("Expert")
        break
    if kill == "C":
        print ("Casual")
        break
```